# Asp.net Identity Entity Framework Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

As I am learning the Identity Framework for my asp.net project,
I am following this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

However, I found this odd error:

> class
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser
>
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter
>   'context' of 'UserStore.UserStore(DbContext,
>   IdentityErrorDescriber)'

[image]

I've followed the exact step given from the tutorial. However, I'm facing this error that I couldn't find on Google. Any idea that caused this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the error - the reason is that I've intended to install the Identity Entity Framework 3.0.0-rc1-final, which is still unstable and therefore failed to install to my project. The solution is to take the package manager console and install the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.1, which is stable.